# Are the docs for setting up licensing good to use?

Tags: android

I am attempting to follow the links on the developer console site to implement licensing for my application and am concerned that the docs don't really line up with the current technology.  In part of the documentation, I was directed to a page that said the utility for doing this was no longer valid.  I am simply looking to get licensing (lvl) setup for my app and am hoping somebody can point me to a good resource.

Here is where I stopped at, as I am not familiar with the whole project library import process.  It sounds I need to run a command line to continue the process but I am not sure what one of the values needs to be.

[image]

I am not sure what the target ID is or if I just need to update the above mentioned properties file or what?

Docs seem to be a little confusing on this topic, or I've just simply missed the boat.

Thanks!